# how to get calendar item change log?

Tags: powershell, calendar, office365, exchange-server

it's supposoed to work with this commandlet

[Get-CalendarDiagnosticObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-calendardiagnosticobjects?view=exchange-ps)

but it's obviously missing from these modules

```
3.0.0      ExchangeOnlineManagement            PSGallery            This is a General Availability (GA) release of the Exchange Online Powershell V3 module....
0.11.0     ExchangePowerShell                  PSGallery            The EP (ExchangePowerShell) Powershell module is a collection of commandlets that can be
```

The term 'Get-CalendarDiagnosticObjects' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,

whereas:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline 
get-mailbox
```

works fine!

seems that V3 of the module is quite new? any idea?

Comment: It is still available in version 2.0.5

Comment: Just updated the module. Looks like it no longer works in 3.0.0. Probably the documentation is out-of-date.

Comment: Also the Module states the following: `However, REST backed EOP and SCC cmdlets are not available yet. To use those, you will need to enable WinRM Basic Auth. 
For more information check https://aka.ms/exov3-module`

Comment: what are EOP and SCC cmdlets?

Comment: EOP is Exchange Online Protection, SCC is Security and Compliance.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be an issue anymore. Be sure to add Get-CalendarDiagnosticAnalysis to your toolbox as well. To be sure this isn't an issue anymore, you could also run `Get-Command -Module ExchangeOnlineManagement`

It should be in that list.